# I can't get a negative value of element that's off the screen to the left

Tags: jquery, css

How would I get the position of my element that's overflowing to the left? I have set my document to be 'overflow: hidden'. The value of the green box on the exact position shows to be 305, where it should be on the negative.

```
alert($('.menu').position().left);
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `.offset()` instead of `.position()`?

Comment: yes, it posts exactly the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this? **[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mrs_snow/rs81qyvb/)**

```
var posOffScreen = $('.menu').offset();
var offLeftPos = posOffScreen.left;
alert(offLeftPos + 'px');
```

Comment: As I explained in my comment. This returns exact the same value.

Comment: it is negative in the fiddle so i'm not sure what you need.  try posting your link somewhere.

Comment: yes, because you're setting `left: -300;` I'm not setting anything to be on negative. I'm setting the right corner to always positive value, but the since container is too wide, the left goes off the left side of the screen.

Comment: I set the right to 300px - and still got the negative number - so you probably need to post a lot more of your code so we can reproduce the issue and see why the browser thinks it's a positive value.